# Reactnative get data and save it asyncstorage

Tags: javascript, react-native

i want to get it these datas(selectData.Gunes,selectData.Imsak....)
and save into asyncstorage, how can i make it ? If i write the asyncstorage code into fetch is this problem? Thx

```
const fetchPray = async county => {
const url4 = '' + county;
console.log(url4);
fetch(url4)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(pray => {
    setPray(pray);
    let index = pray.findIndex(d => d.MiladiTarihKisa === date);
    let selectData = pray[index];

    setVakitGunes(selectData.Gunes);
    setVakitImsak(selectData.Imsak);
    setVakitOgle(selectData.Ogle);
    setVakitIkindi(selectData.Ikindi);
    setVakitAksam(selectData.Aksam);
    setVakitYatsi(selectData.Yatsi);
    setGunTurkce(selectData.MiladiTarihUzun);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have prayer times, such as Fajr, Dhuhr, Asr, Maghrib, Isha, you can store the relevant data as stringifed javascript object like below

```
let p = {
  fajr: '05:30',
  dhuhr: '13:04',
  ...
};

AsyncStorage.getItem('times').then((result) => {

  if (!result) {
    try {
      AsyncStorage.setItem('times', JSON.stringify(p));
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Error : ' + e);
    }

  } else {
    try {
      AsyncStorage.mergeItem('times', JSON.stringify(p));
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Error : ' + e);
    }
  }

});
```